# Is the included derivation feasible? If so, would my proof be correct?

Tags: logic, proof, fitch

The simple derivation seems correct and intuitive, and yet I feel as if something is off.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could double-check the provided formal proof.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your time, help, and consideration.

Comment: Correct........

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.